# Recipe Amounter Converter - While Loop Bug

Tags: python, while-loop, operators

I'm more or less a beginner in python and I'm trying to make a recipe converter (**which converts the number of ingredients needed either multiplied or divided by a whole number**). I'm at a point in my code where this `while` loop I made does not seem to be working right and I'm not sure why. The while loop should repeat the loop if the words do not equal *multiplied* or *divided* and should continue past the loop if it does equal the words.

I'm trying to not heavily change my code and keep it relatively the same. If that's not possible I understand.

```
recipe_name = input("Please enter in the name of your recipe here: ")
 
math_operator = input(
    f"Do you want {recipe_name} multiplied or divided? Enter here: ")
 
operator_lower = math_operator.lower()
 
while operator_lower != "multiplied" and operator_lower != "divided":
    print("\x1B[4m" + "This is not the correct choice." + "\x1B[0m")
    math_operator = input(
        f"Do you want {recipe_name} multiplied or divided? Enter here: ")
```

Comment: Your while condition is based on `operator_lower` whereas your input changes `math_operator` only.  `operator_lower = math_operator.lower()` gets run the first time only, not in the loop

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `operator_lower` also in the loop:

```
recipe_name = input("Please enter in the name of your recipe here: ")

math_operator = input(f"Do you want {recipe_name} multiplied or divided? Enter here: ")
operator_lower = math_operator.lower()

while operator_lower != "multiplied" and operator_lower != "divided":
    print("\x1B[4m" + "This is not the correct choice." + "\x1B[0m")
    math_operator = input(f"Do you want {recipe_name} multiplied or divided? Enter here: ")
    operator_lower = math_operator.lower()
```

You can also simplify you code a bit:

```
recipe_name = input("Please enter in the name of your recipe here: ")

while True:
    math_operator = input(f"Do you want {recipe_name} multiplied or divided? Enter here: ")
    operator_lower = math_operator.lower()
    if operator_lower == "multiplied" or operator_lower == "divided":
        break # Exit the loop immediately.
    else:
        print("\x1B[4m" + "This is not the correct choice." + "\x1B[0m")
```